# Add a share or permalink button to the Android app

Tags: support, android-app

Could you add a menu option for getting a permalink to the current question, so that it can be viewed in a browser when needed? Or just a share button which can copy links also (just like they do in pocket).

Comment: This is a good thing to request. However, I suspect you were being downvoted for the demanding nature of the question, so I've edited away everything that isn't just the request. They apparently had higher priorities than a share button at the start, and complaining it should have been there already won't get it put there any faster.

Comment: Thanks, and I'm really sorry if I have hurt somebodys feelings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer a sentence from your original phrasing,

> This feature should have been implemented from the start.

Agreed, it should have. And it was.

[image: screenhots of the question options dialog]

Comment: Missed that. Can I request the same options to be added to the options menu? Would be much more discoverable. Thanks, and I'm accepting the answer.

Comment: Now this has been answered, does that mean we're stuck with the share feature hidden away like that? How do I upvote this feature request? Not sure the SO format is right for dev requests imho

Comment: I had to attempt to post the exact same question just to get here and find out it was already implemented. *Sigh*

Comment: I came to post the exact same question as well.  As part of a good user interface, I would recommend adding the "share" button to the context menu (the built-in "menu" button on most phones), instead of just leaving it on that pop-up menu.